# Request forbidden by administrative rules reddit api

Tags: php, post, curl, get, reddit

I have a problem with api to reddit. I tried to use php sdk https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk, but for each method from API, I receive message:
403 Request forbidden by administrative rules reddit. I think is i problem with access_token, but I used the one that the returned API. I tried with tutorial from https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/197x36/using_oauth_to_send_valid_requests/c8lz57u, but in step 6 I get same error 403. I obtained the access_token in step 6.

Response in step 6 is:

```
{"access_token": "DhiI6vzq86UlCjTIl80u5pCEZ6A", "token_type": "bearer", "expires_in":       3600, "scope": "edit,flair,history,identity,modconfig,modflair,modlog,modposts,modwiki,mysubreddits,privatemessages,read,report,save,submit,subscribe,vote,wikiedit,wikiread"}
```

Authentication is ok, but I can not call any method from API.

Can someone help me with some advice?

Comment: If you're still having this problem, in order to help, more info is needed: What endpoint is failing (if it's multiple, pick a simple one, such as /api/v1/me)? What are the request headers you're sending? (Obfuscate the access token)